# After init have EXC_BAD_ACCESS to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I create a designer initializer with incoming arguments NSString *
In my class, i have property NSString* title.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *title;
...
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title albumCover:(UIImage *)img {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",title];
        self.img = img;
    }
    return self;
}
```

with variable self.img everything good, but with self.title I have problems. If I want to log self.title I get *error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fcbbff0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.*
I tried to init before assigning, tried to with NSMutableString. Always the same thing. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show the backtrace of the crash, please.  There is nothing wrong with that code, as written (though it is a good idea to avoid using the getter/setter in the initialization and deallocation of an object).   The problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment isn't your problem.  The problem is elsewhere.  While the property declaration and initialization do not follow the recommended pattern, they aren't going to cause a crash in the code you've shown.

The following runs fine, for example.   You should declare your `@property` as `copy` and assign to the instance variable directly (doing so avoids any issues that might spring up if you later implement a custom setter with business logic that requires a fully initialized object).

```
@interface Fo:NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *wrongWay;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *rightWay;
@end

@implementation Fo
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.wrongWay = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",title];
        _rightWay = [title copy];
    }
    return self;
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Fo *f = [[Fo alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fo"];
        NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", f, f.wrongWay, f.rightWay);
    }
    return 0;
}
```